# Android DatePicker invisible header padding

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have an issue where the Android DatePicker within my layout has this huge top margin/padding/header, which I cannot find a way to remove.

I have tried different styling, margins, paddings, parent layouts - anything I could think of. See the white section in the image below. Please assist!

[image]

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_color"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtV_SelectAppointmentDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            app:MvxBind="Text ScheduleTimeSlotText;" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/scheduling_date_datePicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:datePickerMode="calendar"
            android:background="@color/gray_color"/>
```

Comment: have you tried to activate the **layout boundaries in the developer options** to get a better view on the problem

Comment: @K.Dexter I did try evaluate in the design view, but unless im missing something it doesn't give any details to explain the issue. Only shows the white block is part of the datepicker